# if statement causes type error elm

Tags: elm

I want to update a record in Elm of type

```
type CubeData = {currDirection : Vec3, translation : Vec3, transform : Mat4}
```

Which I can use the following code to do.

```
updateCubeData : CubeData -> CubeData
updateCubeData cubeData = {cubeData | translation <- cubeData.currDirection,
                                      transform <- translate cubeData.translation cubeData.transform}
```

However, I now want to update a field of the record differently depending on what the current value of the field is, so I tried doing this

```
 updateCubeData : CubeData -> CubeData
 updateCubeData cubeData = if abs cubeData.translation.x > 2.0 || abs cubeData.translation.y > 2.0
                           then  {cubeData | translation <- cubeData.currDirection,
                                             transform <- translate cubeData.translation cubeData.transform}
                           else  {cubeData | currDirection <- negate cubeData.currDirection,
                                             translation <- cubeData.currDirection,
                                             transform <- translate cubeData.translation cubeData.transform}
```

This is a type error, which I've reproduced below. Note the type signature of `updateCubeData` is the 12th line of the file.

```
Type error on line 15, column 68 to 76:
        cubeData

   Expected Type: {a | y : Float, x : Float}
     Actual Type: Vec3

Type error on line 18, column 68 to 76:
        cubeData

   Expected Type: {a | y : Float, x : Float}
     Actual Type: Vec3

Type error between lines 13 and 18:
        if | ((abs cubeData.translation.x) > 2.0) ||
             ((abs cubeData.translation.y) > 2.0) ->
               {cubeData |
                    translation <- cubeData.currDirection,
                    transform <- translate cubeData.translation cubeData.transform}
           | True ->
               {cubeData |
                    currDirection <- negate cubeData.currDirection,
                    translation <- cubeData.currDirection,
                    transform <- translate cubeData.translation cubeData.transform}

   Expected Type: Vec3
     Actual Type: {a | y : Float, x : Float}
```

If I eliminate the `if` statement, and just set the function equal to the contents of the `then` and `else` the code compiles and runs as expected (if that block was the whole method). Why does adding an if statement as I have here introduce this type error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type error is coming from this part of your code:

`abs cubeData.translation.x > 2.0 || abs cubeData.translation.y > 2.0`

The compiler is complaining that `cubeData.translation` is of type `Vec3` but you are treating it as though it is of type `{a | y : Float, x : Float}`. That is to say that `Vec3` is not a record type containing the fields x and y.

I believe you actually want to use the `getX` and `getY` functions from `Math.vector3`:

`abs (cubeData.translation |> getX) > 2.0 || abs (cubeData.translation |> getY) > 2.0`